# SSTP vpn 50% slower than without vpn

Tags: vpn

I've a W7 Pro computer at home, on which I have set up a sstp vpn gateway. 
The internet connection of this computer is 300Mbps/50Mbps (tested on Speedtest.net)

Now, I am currently not at home (but using a homeline connection) and I'm using the VPN. 
Without VPN, my speed is: 13.3Mbps / 1Mbps
With VPN, my speed is: 6.6Mbps / 1Mbps

When I did this test, the CPU of my home computer was around 5%, so I guess it is not the blocking factor.

Any idea of what could be causing the slowdown ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The bandwith between the two machines is about 6Mbps. Any reason why it is not used maximum bandwith ?

Comment: There's your issue. Reasons may vary, from voluntary throttling by one of the ISPs to links between them being overloaded.

Comment: How can I investigate / fix that ?
And how can my ISP know what is going on on the connection since it should behave like https ?

Comment: Ok
Withtout the vpn, I have a little bit more (7Mbps)
So indeed the connection between the two machines is the problem :/

Comment: You should contact both ISPs, they're the only ones who can help you.

Comment: Thks
I will do that.

But it is the same one on both ends actually.